# Kubuntu 19.10 missing program files

Tags: kubuntu, wine

I have Kubuntu 19.10 installed on my husbands laptop. It is a fresh install. We added wine and winetricks. We installed Ultimaker Cura 4.5 from the appimage. It installed and opened but it is not in the installed applications file. Also I can't find the installed program file. This also happened when we installed Zbrush 2020.1 through Wine. Both installed an opened but once closed we are unable to find the program file. I am not able to open either file again.

Srill pretty new to linux so still learning.

Comment: I found the file but it is some kind of xml and not the actual program. We had it running before and once we installed the program wee found it in the applications graphics file. For some reason this time it is not working.